# Android TextToSpeech is not working on android 1.5

Tags: android, google-translate, android-1.5-cupcake

I am developing Android TextToSpeech app. This application is not working in *Android 1.5*, but it works fine in *Android 1.6*.

I am using `google-api-translate.jar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Text-To-Speech feature is only available in Android 1.6 (API Level 4) and newer! See [TextToSpeech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) class for details!